# how to Query to specific graph to RDF database

Tags: database, sparql, rdf, semantic-web, stardog

Hi i have a rdf database and a graph called as urn:graph:2d6d3d07-20b0-4050-ada8-43e5655c919a and i want to query following construct statement to this graph how can i do that?

```
# Expand From IRIs 
CONSTRUCT {?iri ?predicate ?object .?object a ?object_type .?object <tag:stardog:studio:label> ?object_label_0 .?object rdfs:label ?object_label_1 .?object <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title> ?object_label_2 .?subject ?predicate_2 ?iri .?subject a ?subject_type .?subject <tag:stardog:studio:label> ?subject_label_0 .?subject rdfs:label ?subject_label_1 .?subject <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title> ?subject_label_2 .} 
WHERE {VALUES (?iri) {(<tag:stardog:api:0.13193948493419416>)}
       { ?iri ?predicate ?object .
        OPTIONAL { ?object a ?object_type . }
        OPTIONAL { ?object <tag:stardog:studio:label> ?object_label_0 . }
        OPTIONAL { ?object rdfs:label ?object_label_1 . }
        OPTIONAL { ?object <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title> ?object_label_2 . }
       } UNION {
        ?subject ?predicate_2 ?iri .
        OPTIONAL { ?subject a ?subject_type . }
        OPTIONAL { ?subject<tag:stardog:studio:label> ?subject_label_0 . }
        OPTIONAL { ?subject rdfs:label ?subject_label_1 . }
        OPTIONAL { ?subject <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title> ?subject_label_2 . }
       }
      } LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: just use `GRAPH` keyword before the graph pattern in your `WHERE` clause as shown in the specs at https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#queryDataset or also in the specs build the dataset before the `WHERE` clause, i.e. `CONSTRUCT {} FROM ... FROM NAMED ... WHERE {}`, see https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#specifyingDataset

Comment: @UninformedUser like 'construct {} from named<graphid> where{}'  ?

Comment: just use `CONSTRUCT { ... } WHERE { GRAPH <graphid> { ... } }` and you are done.